# How to use multi-entry and history-mode react-router at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, history

For example, I have two pages `localhost:8080/index.html` and `localhost:8080/entry.html`. When I use `localhost:8080/entry.html/main` and `localhost:8080/entry.html/person` with the `react-router` like this

```html
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={'/main'} render={<Main />}>
    <Route exact path={'/person'} render={<Person />}>
  <Switch>
</Router>
```

It it not working perfectly and somehow when I refresh the page I get `Cannot GET /subject.html/main`.

I try

```html
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
<Router basename="/subject.html">
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={'/main'} render={<Main />}>
    <Route exact path={'/person'} render={<Person />}>
  <Switch>
</Router>
```

or

```js
    devServer: {
        ....
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        publicPath: '/'
    },
```

and it is not working.
Please tell me how to do this. Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize it by myself.
First of all, at the development environment, we required to config alike this.

```json
historyApiFallback: {
    verbose: true,
    rewrites: [
        {from: /^\/entry\/.*$/, to: '/entry.html'}, 
    ],
},
```

It mean whenever we load `localhost:8080/entry/main`, it will redirect to `localhost:8080/entry.html/main`.

Along with deploy environment, you need to write the nginx alike this.

```js
  location / {
    rewrite ^/entry/(.+?) /entry.html/$1 last
  }
```